# How to save a score/highscore (int) in a surfaceview class?

Tags: android, save, int, surfaceview

Im trying to save a highscore, in my game. My class extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceHolder.Callback. So the scoring system works perfect but I really want to make a highscore system (you know first see if score is your highest, if it is set it as highscore).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref